# Is the Inventory in Diablo 3 larger for Collector's Edition?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have the Collector's Edition of Diablo 3 and play online with people whom have either bought the downloaded version or the disk version of the game. I have been noticing that they have to go to town to unload goods more often then I do. When I have shown them screen shots of my inventory they claim the it is about twice as big as what they have available to them.

Is this true that you get a bigger inventory with Collector's Edition versus other versions? I wouldn't think so but am not sure given their comments.

UPDATE: Screenshot of my inventory. 60 slots total. BTW, I am mostly convinced they are hoarders but just want independent confirmation. :) 
[image]

Comment: it would probably be helpful if you included a SS of your inventory

Comment: Well it is the "Collector's" Edition. For collecting more things. *Rimshot*

Comment: I will grab my SS later today and post. Just not at that machine now.

Comment: Your friends are hoarders.

Comment: Maybe your friends pick up white or grey items and you don't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Collector Edition does not affect the gameplay. You are most likely picking up fewer items than your friends.

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/services/collectors-edition/

Comment: Technically you have less room, with the wings and dyes taking up 3 slots.

Comment: Double checked against their SS. 60 slots less 3 for my bonus items. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, it's possible you pick up fewer items than your friends (Maybe they pick up white/grey which are not worth picking up?), or maybe you simply purchased additional stash space which is why yours looks larger than theirs.

Collector's edition definitely doesn't give you more than cosmetic bonuses.